# Edit to comment template?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, answers, low-quality-posts

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277470/42315) was posted recently. Werner commented. I saw this through the LQ queue, and I commented. This motivated me for this question.

That comment template:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

seems like a -- typically correct -- remark, and nothing more. A user seeing this comment is left with "Well so what? I can't «critique» till I have enough rep?", and no knowledge of possible conversions. Perhaps we should add a sentence to the template to mention this? Something like:

> I've [flagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this "answer" for moderator attention, requesting it be converted to a comment to *the question*.

This way the user knows something is being done about this inappropriate placing. It is also unfortunate that the user of the linked answer can't yet flag…

Comment: As you can imagine from the autistic tone, they are added by the system via the review actions.

Comment: If there is a reasonable man-made (i.e. not boilerplate) comment by  another user, i just *recommend deletion without a comment* if i think it should be deleted. Those boilerplates aren't really to my liking anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some points to consider:

1. This template forms part of the Low Quality/LQ review queue "delete" reasons:

   [image]

   As such, it's a canned response and should cover a whole host of possible "non-answer answers". By adding this to the response, you have to ask yourself the question: "Is it really necessary to convert all non-answers into comments?"
2. The idea behind the LQ review queue is to remove the moderation burden partially from the [moderators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). As such, having a canned response direct content back to them seems to defeat the purpose.
3. Being able to [comment is a privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Sure, it's a pain to raise your voice when you're just starting out, but [there are reasons for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/168244).

With the above in mind, I'd suggest to leave the burden of conversion-to-comment up to the community members through flagging.

[Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) references:

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/168244)
- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/168244)